# How to generate an LL(2) parse table?

Tags: compilers, parsers, ll-k

The algorithms I've seen for building an LL(1) parse table involve calculating `first` and `follow` sets such that:

```
predict(nonterminal, production) == 
     if epsilon in FIRST(production):
         first(production) union follow(nonterminal)
     else:
         first(production)
```

where production is a sequence of symbols which can include nonterminals, terminals, and epsilon.

what's the algorithm for an LL(2) parse table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pretty reasonable discussion in [this essay from the SLK parser generator](http://www.slkpg2.com/llkparse.html).

Basically, you just need to extend $FIRST$ and $FOLLOW$ to be $FIRST_k$ and $FOLLOW_k$, meaning the first / following $k$ symbols. The basic principle is the same, but when $k > 1$ there is a complication, leading to the distinction between "strong" and regular grammars.

The naming is a bit counterintuitive; the parsing table for a strong grammar can be generated by an easier but less powerful algorithm, so the strong grammars are in a sense weaker; they make a stronger guarantee about predictability.